# FancyBox 3 Zoom Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, zooming, fancybox-3

I am using FancyBox 3 and wanted to have a zoom button in the buttons bar, but can't seem to make it work.

I am using clickContent to open a link, and I thought that since I have the Zoom function, I could call that somehow on a button toggle instead of clicking on the content.

I made a button with btnTpl, giving it a class of "fancybox-zoom".

I tried this (and a couple of other things, but none of these works)

```
afterLoad : function() {
                $(".fancybox-zoom").click(function(current,event) {
                    return current.type === 'image' ? 'zoom' : false;
                });
            },
```

Where/how should I call the click function or what am I doing wrong? :)

**EDIT:** Actually I found out that the function I need is scaleToActual but when I make it an onclick event on the button like this:

```
<button onclick="$.fancybox.scaleToActual()" data-fancybox-zoom class="fancybox-button fancybox-zoom"></button>
```

It drops the `Uncaught TypeError: $.fancybox.scaleToActual is not a function` error... any ideas about this method?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: fancyBox supports multiple instances, therefore you need to have a reference to the instance. For example: $.fancybox.getInstance().scaleToActual();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be like this:

```
$( '[data-fancybox]' ).fancybox({
  onInit : function( instance ) {

    // Make zoom icon clickable
    instance.$refs.toolbar.find('.fancybox-zoom').on('click', function() {

      if ( instance.isScaledDown() ) {
        instance.scaleToActual();

      } else {
        instance.scaleToFit();
      }

    });
  }
});
```

Demo - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boGPZx

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply and the demo, works perfectly, this is exactly what I needed. :)